# Proof of stake, mauve paper - glossary of terms

Tags: proof-of-stake, sharding, epoch, mauve-paper

Just getting my head around some of the concepts in [Vitalik Buterin's Mauve paper](http://vitalik.ca/files/mauve_paper3.html).

There are a few terms for which I don't yet have a clear definitions. These include the terms below (shown with my present interpretation):

- **Validator** - a computer that confirms validity of all (or part) of the Ethereum Virtual Machine (EVM) state
- **Epoch** - [a 100 hour window](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining#so-what-is-mining-anyway)
- **Shard** - a distinct chunk of the whole EVM state (see also [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/573/820))
- **Dunkle** - Proof of stake version of an uncle

I'm guessing these terms will eventually end up [here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Glossary), but, in the meantime, **can anyone provide a glossary of terms for the mauve paper?**

Comment: In my limited understanding validators are the equivalent of miners in a PoW setting. They will be the responsible of processing, archiving, maintaining the transactions while they keep a certain amount of Ether locked at stake. that progressively, as Ethereum matures, will have more and more decentralized roles and won't have to keep up with the entire state of the network (ex. with sharding). For the rest I would also like to hear some extended explanations.

Comment: relevant -> https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Sharding-FAQ#what-is-sharding

Comment: The paper link to vitalik.ca no longer works (404). There's a [copy on cdn.hackaday.io](https://cdn.hackaday.io/files/10879465447136/Mauve%20Paper%20Vitalik.pdf) - not sure it's the same one linked here.