# Experimental data on transaction propagation time

Tags: cpp-ethereum, network, peers, transaction-propagation

Does anyone have empirical data on how long does it take to propogate a transaction thought out most of blockchain?
I know we can speculate on how long it would take (like [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30685/what-are-the-average-transaction-propagation-times-in-ethereum-for-reaching-50)). But I am interested in real measurements, since I am not sure the guesstimate holds up in real world.

On etherscan sometimes transaction appears in 5 seconds after I submit it and sometimes it takes up to 15 seconds. Etherscan tells me this:

> 2. It could still be in the TX Pool of a different node, waiting to be broadcasted.
> 3. When the network is busy it can take a while for your transaction to propagate through the network and for us to index it.

I wonder if propagation can actually take so long (which is contrary to guesstimate of 400ms [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30685/what-are-the-average-transaction-propagation-times-in-ethereum-for-reaching-50)). Or is it just a problem on Etherscan's part. To answer this I would really like to see some experimental data. Thanks!