# Subscribe to new txpool transactions on geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, txpool

I know that the *state* of the txpool of a geth node can be queried using the [txpool API](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#txpool). However, I was wondering if it is somehow possible to *subscribe* to new transactions entering a geth node's txpool, possibly on a websockets or local socket rpc connection? I'd like to write the program that subscribes to new txpool transactions in Go as well.

I discovered this subscription in [go-ethereum internally](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth?tab=doc#EthAPIBackend.SubscribeNewTxsEvent), but it doesn't look like it's exposed, unfortunately.

Note that I'm not only talking about local pending transactions ([answered here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/49420/monitoring-pending-transactions)), but all transactions arriving to the txpool.

Background: I'd like to do research on frontrunning. The authors of the [Flash Boys 2.0 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05234) released their [geth fork on github](https://github.com/pdaian/flashboys2), which they used to observe gas auctions in the txpool. However, using a fork is not as reusable and maintainable than having the possibility to extend geth's API so that external applications can subscribe to txpool udpates.

Comment: Hey sebastian did you find something to solve the problem?

Comment: Not really. I wanted to use it from within Go code but go-ethereum doesn't expose the `pendingTransactions` subscription on the `ethclient` API. It seems to be available (sometimes) wiht JS web3 though, see Eugene's answer.

Comment: I did find asolution actually but it uses web3.py

Comment: do you have github? or twitter?

Answer (score 6):

We have been running [ethviewer.live](http://ethviewer.live/) since late 2017 with a modified geth client. It has certainly been painful to keep up with latest versions of geth. Also, we have had outages when we were unable to keep up with forks.
As suggested by @Eugene I tried with `web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')` and it seems to be working fine. One caveat though -- Subscription API on Geth is best-effort, which means it may occasionally miss out a TX or block. If you need all data, you need to do state management and pull any missing data using Web3.eth functions. As per GitHub discussions, Geth may not fix this, while Parity seems to fix it.

As you are interested in frontrunning, be aware that a node gets large fraction of transactions after the block containing them is received. For e.g., with `--maxpeers = 50` on [ethviewer.live](http://ethviewer.live/) about 40% of transactions arrived after the block containing them arrived (i.e., either block timestamp or arrival time < transaction arrival time). I also checked by dumping [blockchair.com](https://blockchair.com) transaction pool and realized the fraction is about 55% (don't know what they used as `--maxpeers`). These measurements were done for several days. So you may want to play with high `--- maxpeers` values in addition to having good bandwidth.

Comment: How did you go about testing your claim that 40% of txs arrived after the block containing them arrived?

Comment: We locally log the time that block and TX announcements are received by our node. For a ~2 months trace, ~40% of the TXs were received by our node after the block that contain them were received, i.e., block had an earlier local timestamp than TXs. I tried with --maxpeers = 25 and = 5. Didn't observe a significant improvement.

Comment: @DilumBandara I have experienced the same phenomen. About 35-40% come in to late, even by more than 10 seconds! Have you experimented with nodes in different locations around the world? Is there any reason to explain this? Looking at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/28679 it should not be an issue to receive all but a few outliers in time.

Comment: @PlusUltra We haven't tried it across geographies. I think it comes down to a factors such as bandwidth, peers connected to, and transaction originating peer. We have seen sometimes 200+ new transactions arrive to the pool within a 1 sec. Given transaction arrival is bursty, network is massive, we are connected only to 25 nodes (out of 5,000+), and inter-block time for some blocks is 2-5 sec, there's no way a gossip protocol is going to disseminate them before the next block arrives.  There's an error in my previous comment. It should be "I tried with --maxpeers = 25 and = 50"

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit counterintuitive, but while [`web3.eth.getPendingTransactions()`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth.html#getpendingtransactions) returns only local pending transactions (`from` transaction field value matching accounts within the node), [`web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions')`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html#subscribe-pendingtransactions) will return a stream of global pending transactions.

Please find usage examples [here](https://support.chainstack.com/hc/en-us/articles/900003426246-Subscribing-to-global-new-pending-transactions).

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that `subscribe('pendingTransactions')` does cover all incoming txs in the pool. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be exposed in go-ethereums [ethclient](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client).

Comment: Eugene, I tried your examples from the link. I am connected directly on a node via icp. The problem is, I get only a stream of tx which are already mined. Not pending anymore. I have to say I do not use the geth client but opera of fantom. Do you have an idea if this is a general setting maybe somewhere which can be changed?

Comment: How does the node get access to global pending txs without them also becoming local? Is it because `subscribe(pendingTransactions)` queries neighboring nodes' txpools, which might have larger sizes and not fit in the current node's local mempool?

Answer (score 3):

Supplement to Eugene's answer, I have [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuzhong/ecau2sLm/11/) testing the speed of two nodes catching pending transactions. It was built with web3.subscription. Hope it helps.

Explanation of the code is also [here](https://chainstack.com/evm-speed-tester/).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an account with Infura and subscribe to their pending pool as easy as this:

```
const { time } = require("console");
const Web3 = require("web3");
let fs = require('fs');


const web = new Web3();

const rpcUrl = 'INFURA NODE RPC'

const web3 = new Web3(rpcUrl)

const message = fs.createWriteStream("./pendingPool.txt");

message.write("tx-hash" + ' ' + "Arrival" + "\n");

var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('pendingTransactions', function (error, result) {
    if (error)
        console.log(error)
})
    .on("data", function (result) {
        message.write(result + ' ' + Date.now() + "\n");
    });
```

This code listens to the pending pool and writes the tx and arrival time to a file.